# How to deselect a flex datagrid row by clicking on it?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3

I have a question for a simple thing that there doesn't seem to be a simple solution to. I have a datagrid, and the rows should be deselected if it's clicked on and already selected. How to do that?

I'm looking at the different "item"-events but the row is already selected when they are dispatched, so there is no way to tell if it was already selected or not.

Can someone help me out here with a very simple thing that I've probably missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

    <mx:Array id="arr1">
        <mx:Object label="One fish" />
        <mx:Object label="Two fish" />
        <mx:Object label="Tree fish" />
        <mx:Object label="Four fish" />
    </mx:Array>

    <mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid2"
                    click="test(event)"
                    dataProvider="{arr1}"
                    draggableColumns="false"
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%" >
                    <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="label" width="50" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var lastIndex :Number = -1;
            private function test(evt:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(dataGrid2.selectedIndex == lastIndex)
                    dataGrid2.selectedIndex = -1;

                lastIndex = dataGrid2.selectedIndex;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a simple and working solution. I was just wondering if you can solve it with event handling so you don't have to use an extra class variable?

Comment: Unfortunatly, it doesn't work for AdvancedDataGrid as set selectedIndex = -1 does nothing.
Use selectIndices to know if some rows are selected... But cannot deselect setting also selectIndices to empty array...